# F# Record Structural Comparison Ordering

Tags: f#, recordtype, structural-equality

If I have an record such as:

```
type MyDate =
    { Year  : int
      Month : int
      Day   : int }
```

I know that F#'s structural comparison will ensure that when a list is sorted it will maintain a consistent order.

**My question** is whether I can rely on it to do the comparison in a specific way, and what that way is?

For example with the `MyDate` record above: if it compares each field in the order they were declared then I could assume the following:
`{ Year: 2010; Month: 9: Day: 8 } > { Year: 2009; Month: 10; Day: 20 }`

I've struggled to find the documentation that describes how the structure equality for Record types work. I can see from the Fsharp.Core tests how tuple comparison works: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/cb6cb5c410f537c81cf26825657ef3bb29a7e952/tests/fsharp/core/attributes/test.fsx#L737, but I can't seem to find a similar test for Record types.

Answer (score 6):

Ah, straight after I posted the question I managed to find the answer:

From the language spec: https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf

> 8.15.4 Behavior of the Generated CompareTo Implementations
>
> ...
>
> • If T is a struct or record type, invoke FSharp.Core.Operators.compare on each corresponding pair of fields of x and y in declaration order, and return the first non-zero result.

So in the above `MyDate` example, when comparing two instances it will:

1. compare the `Year` fields first
2. then if the years are the same it will compare the `Month` fields
3. then if the months are the same it will compare the `Day` fields